# C# Order quantity split as per warehouse

Tags: c#, linq, permutation

I am working on an application for order management. One order contains multiple products and each product is present in a warehouse, now I have to find the best possible combination to split order quantity to put into packages based on shipping cost.

For examples, i have two warehouse W1, W2. Customer orders two products P1 with quantity 9 and product P2 with quantity 1. The situation is product P2 is present only in warehouse W1 and product P1 is present in both the warehouses. Now I want to find all possible combinations to divide this order into two packages to find the cheapest cost. Each of the warehouse where quantity is less than or equals to 5(per package limit is 5) it cost flat rate($5) and anything greater than quantity 5 costs flat rate + additional cost. The additional cost for W1 is $1 and for W2 is $2.

`Product      W1      W2
     P1         9
     P2         1     N/A`

`Product      W1      W2
    P1         8       1
    P2         1       N/A`

`Product      W1      W2
    P1         7       2
    P2         1       N/A
    .
    .
    .`

`Product      W1      W2
    P1         1       8
    P2         1       N/A`

`Product      W1      W2
    P1                 9
    P2         1       N/A`

I am able to create such list on paper and calculated the cost and the best combination I found is, flat rate W1 send one package $5 and W2 send another package $5, so total cost is $10, no additional cost came in the picture because quantity in a package does not exceed 5. I have so far created a dictionary with warehouse as key and list of products from each order as per availability but I am not able to proceed with this combination and need some help. Is this something linq can help?.

`Product     W1      W2
     P1        4       5
     P2        1       N/A`

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, you do not need to pass over the whole permutations. I wouldn't use LINQ as well. Just straightforward, write order planner service with the algorithm like:

For any product,

- If the order count is less than or equal to 5, firstly, try to use all of them from **W2**. If **W2** capacity is not enough, use as much as you can from **W2**, then use the remaining count from **W1**.
- If the order count is greater than 5. Firstly, try to use 5 of them from **W2**. If **W2** capacity is not enough, use as much as you can from **W2**, then use the remaining whole count from W1.

If you apply this algorithm to your example, you will directly get the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for the info, will try to implement it.

Comment: If it helps you, please mark as accepted answer. If you any other question about implementation, you can also ask.